# Advertise through email

Tags: freelance-websites, attracting-clients, communication, negotiation, marketing

So I'm starting a basic business of consulting for web, mobile, desktop, games development. I have seen some business website around my neighborhood that really need rework or upgrade, so i was thinking of contacting them directly through email and tell them that I provide some services that could help them pay less and a better presentation for their customers.

Is this too pushy or a wrong way to do it? And if not, can you provide me an example?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Have you **ever**, for *any reason*, answered a marketing/sales email from a sender you did not personally recognize?

I get about 6-10 of the, *"Hi, I'm a web developer that can improve your site"* emails every single day. Some better crafted than others...

If you think such a campaign will be fruitful, I'd reconsider. If there were to be *any* chance of hitting someone actually willing to respond, one would need to send hundreds, if not thousands, of emails in hopes of a 0.01% response rate. The more "internet aware" the targets, the lower the response rate will be.

Perhaps it is merely my opinion, but I find such campaigns **nothing but a waste of time** - both on the part of the seller and for the prospective client.

"Spam" or unsolicited sales emails really only *work* when there is *product* to be sold which may gain the target's interest, or the target is *already familiar* with the seller - i.e. Amazon sending spam about latest deals.

Answer (score 3):

If you really can **create something** and then **sell it**, and you need to convince others that you can do it well, it's much better to **really create something** and show the world what you've got. No need to talk about what you can, you need to show what you **have done**.

The website of some company looks bad to you? You can make it better? Great! Make your own version of the site on a free domain. Show them. Offer to give it to them for free or for a symbolic amount. And if your offer is accepted, this site will be the first element of your portfolio.
**And this portfolio will worth a lot more than any emails about how good you are.**
Believe me.

Answer (score 3):

Cold calling is hard work. I have had some success emailing potential clients by:

1. making it clear I am a web developer in the same geographic area
2. describing a specific (non-trivial) problem with their website that I can fix
3. showing my experience
4. estimating the cost and time frame for delivery

For example, there was an interesting hack on Joomla 1.5 websites a couple of years ago that defaced pages by adding a specific text string to the top of the affected pages. This made it very easy to find affected websites using a search engine.

I sent the following email to locally affected clients and my success rate was about 1 new client for every 30 emails I sent:

> **Subject: Sorry to say, your website has been hacked**
>
> Based on the ";} /*B6D1B1EE*/ ?>" text in the top left hand corner of
>   the website, it appears that your website at
>   http://www.???????????.com.au has been hacked. See
>   https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=933020 for details.
>
> I am a local (Tasmanian) Joomla website security expert e.g. see
>   http://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/180/120 and can help with cleaning
>   and updating the website to make it safe from hackers.
>
> I estimate that it will take up to 2 hours @ $88/hr (inc. GST) to
>   re-secure the website.
>
> Assuming you don't already have this in hand, please let me know if
>   you'd like my help by replying to this email.
>
> My turn around on fixing hacked Joomla websites is usually one or two
>   business days.
>
> All the best and I look forward to hearing back from you.

Comment: Interesting. My *first* thought would be *you* were the hacker looking to stir up (blackmail) clients to make some money.

Comment: Yes, no doubt this is probably what most email recipients would have thought. I was able to clarify this for the people that replied. This might not be the best example but hopefully you can see how the response / conversion rate can be improved by relating to something specific about the target website.